# Elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]/(X^2+X+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

I need to show that $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]/(X^2+X+1) = \{0, 1, X^2,X+1 \}$.

My own attempt:

Take $f \in \mathbb{Z}_2[X]$. Then dividing by $X^2+X+1$ gives $f = q(X^2+X+1)+r$ for some $q,r\in\mathbb{Z}_2[X]$ and $\deg(r)<2$. Since this implies that $r$ must be a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]$ of degree $-\infty$, $0$ or $1$, I'd say the only possibilities for $r$ should be $0$, $1$, $X$ and $X+1$.

Is, in this field, $X^2 = X$? If so, how do I see this?

Comment: I believe $X^2 = X+1$ in this field: $X^2 + X +1 = 0 \Rightarrow X^2 = -X -1 = X +1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have $X^2=X^2+X+1+X+1$ and thus $X^2\equiv X+1\pmod {X^2+X+1}$ and thus $$\mathbb{Z}_2[X]/(X^2+X+1)=\{0,1,X,X+1\}$$

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `\pmod` instead of typing `mod` with parenthesis.

Comment: @Ennar Thank You! I edited

Comment: @PaleBlueDot You 're welcome!